# setting up dsn for a sql server express database

Tags: sql-server-2008, odbc, dsn

How do i set up a system dsn for a 64 bit sql server express 2008 R2 that is installed on the local machine?

I go to add a system dsn and select sql server native client 10 and follow the wizard. However on the dropdown that asks which sql server to connect, i dont see any option for the local machine. Is there something that i need to enable??

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ignore the drop down and try typing in `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` and see if that works?

Comment: Thank You that helped..i had a named instance of sql server..so i had to use (local)\nameoftheinstance and it worked!!! Thanks a lot...I also enabled named pipes in sql server configuration manager..is that necessary??? Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Sql Express always installs as a named instance called `SQLExpress`. You only need to enable named pipes if you are going to connect to it via named pipes. Some guidance on which protocol to use here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187892%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you can connect informing the IP, localhost or the machine name. If you use the name, SQL Server browser must be running